# Setting positions in a plot - Matplotlib Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, networkx

I'm trying to draw a network using matplotlib as follows:

```
color_map = []
for i in T.nodes():
    if i in colour4:
        color_map.append('green')
    elif i in colour3:
        color_map.append('red')
    else: 
        color_map.append('purple')



color_map_2 = []
for i in T.edges():
    if i in newsettt:
        color_map_2.append('blue')
    elif i in edges:
        color_map_2.append('cyan')
    elif i in edges2:
        color_map_2.append('magenta')
    else: 
        color_map_2.append('black')   

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20)) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos=pos, node_size=15, node_color=color_map, node_shape='o', alpha=1.0)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(T,pos=pos,width=1.0, edge_color=color_map_2, style='solid', alpha=None)
```

But, node positions for the nodes in `colour4` are in the dictionary called `pos22` and node positions for the nodes in `colour3` are in the dictionary called `pos2`. Also, all other coordinates in the dictionary called `pos`.

When I try to draw the network using above code, it doesn't give me the correct diagram as the positions are not defined.

How can I include those three dictionaries to draw the networks correctly?

Comment: where is your `pos` variable?

Comment: @user2906838, What did you mean by that? `nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos=pos,...)` doesn't do the jjob correctly,because my nodes are in 3 different `pos` dictionaries.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just create a dictionary with all of the various position dictionaries put together?